# How can you align multiple figures vertically with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used the following code to align multiple images vertically in bootstrap:

```
<div class="container border rounded overflow">
    <div class="row text-center p-2 flex-nowrap" id="anID">
      
        <img src="../../static/img1.jpg" width=15% alt="">
      
    
        <img src="../../static/mg2.jpg" width=15% alt="">
     
...
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the result:
Multiple pictures next to each other in a rounded container:
[image]

I want to achieve the same thing but with figures. Using the same code doesn't work. It just makes them appear on top of each other, Like this:
[image]

```
<div class="container border rounded">
    <div class="row text-center pt-2 px-2" id="anotherID">
      
        <figure>
          <img src="../../static/img2.jpg" width=15% alt="">
          <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
      
        <figure>
          <img src="../../static/img3.jpg" width=15% alt="">
          <figcaption>another caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
      
        ...
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has class `d-flex` that sets child elements next to each other. In other words it make element with class name `d-flex` a **flex container** and it's direct child to **flex-items**.

```css
.d-flex{
 display:flex;
}
```

It has `display:flex` property in general.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container border rounded">
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap text-center pt-2 px-2" id="anotherID">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2NFZ.png" width="30%" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2NFZ.png" width="30%" class="img-fluid" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      <figcaption>another caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2NFZ.png" width="30%" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      <figcaption>another caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2NFZ.png" width="30%" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      <figcaption>another caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2NFZ.png" width="30%" alt="">
      <figcaption>another caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>Just for your reference I am showing below part how bootstrap works</h1>
<div class="container border rounded">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2NFZ.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2NFZ.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2NFZ.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2NFZ.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! Do you know how I can make the pictures bigger (not their full size, that would be too big) but have it still be responsive?

Comment: I highly recommend you to go through bootstrap documentation how ```row``` ```col``` will work as it has ```lg```,```md```,```xl``` this are the classes and also it works on ```grid-12```, try to practice and play with those classes

Answer (score 0):

### Please try it with bootstrap

```
<div class="container border rounded overflow">
    <div class="row text-center pt-2 px-2 align-item-center justify-content-start overflow-auto flex-nowrap" id="anotherID">
      
        <figure width=15%>
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/E4E4E4" alt="">
          <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure width=15%>
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/E4E4E4" alt="">
          <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure width=15%>
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/E4E4E4" alt="">
          <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure width=15%>
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/E4E4E4" alt="">
          <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure width=15%>
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/E4E4E4" alt="">
          <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure width=15%>
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/E4E4E4" alt="">
          <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure width=15%>
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/E4E4E4" alt="">
          <figcaption>a caption</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! If I use this the images will be full size again (so way to big). If I make the changes you recommended and also add width=15% to the images in the figure, the figure will be too wide and the pictures to far apart. Do you happen to know how to fix that too?